# ORA-39001: ORA-39000: ORA-31640: ORA-27041: and Linux-x86_64 Error: 13: Permission denied

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, import, oracle-xe, impdp, expdp

I used this command to export data:

```
expdp gsw/password DIRECTORY=gsw DUMPFILE=gsw.dmp logfile=gsw.log SCHEMAS=GSW
```

Now importing this to other server as:

```
[root@linux gsw]# impdp gsw/password remap_tablespace=SYSTEM:GSW remap_tablespace=USERS:GSW dumpfile=GSW-31-08-2018.dmp directory=gsw

Import: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Sat Sep 1 11:17:47 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
ORA-39001: invalid argument value
ORA-39000: bad dump file specification
ORA-31640: unable to open dump file "/u01/app/oracle/admin/XE/dpdump/gsw/GSW-31-08-2018.dmp" for read

ORA-27041: unable to open file
Linux-x86_64 Error: 13: Permission denied
Additional information: 9
```

I googled but not able to fix it. Please advise

Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is `Linux-x86_64 Error: 13: Permission denied`

```
cd /u01/app/oracle/admin/XE/dpdump/
 chmod 777 -R gsw
```

Then login as oracle user and run the same command again